# PHP calculating the intersect of arrays

Tags: php

Array declaration: `$uids = array();`

Next these arrays may or may not be created:

```
$uids['locations'];
$uids['ages'];
$uids['genders'];
```

If at least 2 of them are created I want to calculate the intersect. If all 3 are created I want the intersect of all 3.

So, I may want to calculate the intersect of `$uids['locations']` and `$uids['ages']` or the intersect of `$uids['ages']` and `$uids['genders']`, etc.

If put all 3 arrays in array_intersect then I get errors if one of them is not an array. I'm not sure how to handle this without an awful lot of if:else statements and think there is a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that you don't have more array keys than the ones specified, you can use this:

```
$intersect = array();
if (count($uids) > 1) {
    $intersect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $uids);
}
```

Otherwise you could try this one:

```
$_uids = array_intersect_key($uids, array(
    'locations' => 1,
    'ages' => 1,
    'genders' => 1,
));
if (count($uids) > 1) {
    $intersect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $_uids);
}
```

Comment: @soulmerge: great solution, +1! But in this case we cannot specify which items to intersect

Comment: duh, haters gonna hate. Updated answer

Comment: @soulmerge: Ooops, sry, I didn't see the `_array` part. That's a really nice solution! +1